# OpenNI range of returned coordinates

Tags: coordinates, coordinate-systems, openni

I am using the HandsGenerator class of OpenNI, and I want to use it to track the users' movements.

I've registered my own callback for getting the updated position of the hand, and everything works fine, except I can't find information about the coordinate system etc. of the returned `XnPoint3D`. Is there a spec somewhere that precisely specifies the X,Y,Z ranges, and perhaps scaling information (so that I would know that say a change of 100 in the `XnPoint3D`'s `X` corresponds to a movement of 10 centimeters, or something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HandsGenerator returns real world coordinates in millimeters from the sensor. This means that depth points that are right in the middle of the depthmap will have an X and Y of 0.

A change of 100 (in X, Y, or Z) is indeed a change of 10 centimeters (100mm = 10cm).

The range of the X an Y values depends on the Z value of the hand point. Assuming you have a hand point at the top left of the depthmap (or 0,0 in projective coordinates) the possible X and Y values depend on how far away the hand is. The closer the hand, the smaller X and Y. To get the max range your hand positions can be you should choose an arbitrary max Z value and then find the X & Y values of the corners of the depth map at that distance. Or in other words - convert the projective coordinates (0,0,maxZ) and (DepthmapWidth,DepthmapHeight,maxZ) to real world coordinates. All hand points that have a Z value less than maxZ will fall between those 2 real world coordinates)

Note that you can convert projective coordinates to real world using DepthGenerator::ConvertProjectiveToRealWorld.

Comment: Thanks. So basically the coordinates it reports are in mm. Is there a place where information like this is so I don't have to ask every time?

Comment: I didn't find any information about the scale (i.e. that a change of 100 in X,Y,Z is a change of 10 cm) there...